# jquery calls cause problems with server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

After multiple call to ajax function, I noticed a very large number of processes lanced and my website is blocked (but it works well on localhost).

What is the relation between jquery call and the processes?
Is the security of the hosting who blocks it?.

I have many functions doing an automatic refresh. How do I refresh without blocking my website?

---

```
var auto_refresh3 = setInterval( function () { 
    //tchata2.php is a file checking the new messages  
     $.post("tchata2.php",{FID:identif},function (data){
          if($('#newmsg').val()!=data){ 
              $('#newmsg').empty(); 
              $("#newmsg").append(data);
          } 
     });
}, 1000); // checking for other messages after 1 second
```

Comment: The ajax requests are too frequent. It can break the browser.

Comment: what is the solution

Comment: "my website is blocked" => is it the browser window or the server who serves your website?

Comment: the server block my web site (from my side) mean my window because a lot of requests.

Comment: Solution is either 1) buy a better server 2) make the requests less frequent / better performing (ie returns less data, or does less work on the server) 3) use websockets (if applicable) 4) all of the above

Answer (score 1):

Calling the function again after a delay inside the ajax complete will be a better idea and increase the time delay. Using `setInterval` in the outside  will send multiple consecutive requests which can break the browser because of excess memory usage.

```
var auto_refresh3 = function () { 
     $.post("tchata2.php",{FID:identif},function (data){
          if($('#newmsg').val()!= data){ 
              $('#newmsg').empty();
              $("#newmsg").append(data);
          } 
          setTimeout(auto_refresh3, 5000);
     }).fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         setTimeout(auto_refresh3, 5000);
     });
}
```

Comment: now i have just a small problem :) when i click many times cuickly in a link it causes the same problem solved by your answer how can i solve it

Comment: it call just one time

Comment: just one call i need it call itself each 5seconds

Comment: @KhattabMahmoudi that's probably because the ajax is error.

Comment: @KhattabMahmoudi I updated the answer, using that will call it again if there is an error, but its better if you can find out why the error is happenig.

Comment: setTimeout is like setInterval calling many times or just one call after a delai?

Comment: @KhattabMahmoudi `setTimeout` works only once with a delay. But here in my code I am calling the function again with a delay every time ajax is completed.

Comment: NO it's called just one time